# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. now inside the login view, when the user click on submit , the following exception will be raised:-

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

now i commnted the

```
connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />-->
      </providers>
```

from the machine.config file under this location:-

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config
```

but it did not solve the problem,, can anyone adivce on this please ?
Thanks

**EDIT**

here is the whole web.config file:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, &#xA;            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="DomainConnectionString" connectionUsername="Tgroup\administrator" connectionPassword="******" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>

      </providers>
    </membership>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DomainConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://WIN-SPDev.Tgroup.local/OU=Domain Controllers,DC=Tgroup,DC=local"/>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Here is the complete error:-

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 



Line 249:      <providers>
Line 250:        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
Line 251:        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
Line 252:      </providers>
Line 253:    </membership>
```

Comment: The correct version of the mysql dll is present in your bin folder?

Comment: @ThomasLielacher  but i am not using mysql ,, i even did not connect my project to any database yet.. i just add a Home controller and an Account controller,, can you adivce ?

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911096/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-web-version-6-8-3-0/29148048#29148048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What references does your project have?  Even though you're not referencing MySql directly, it could be that you have a reference to an assembly that has a dependency on a particular version of MySql.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes i have a reference to "System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" can you check my edit to the original question, i provided my web.config file..thanks

Comment: What about the web.config file in the Views folder?  Any MySql stuff in there?  If not, just do a text search on the whole solution for "MySql".  The error makes it sound like it's got to be hiding in a config file somewhere.

Comment: no there is no MySql inside my whole solution. the strange thing is that in the exception it showed two entities inside the <Provider> tag, and on line 251 i will raise the exception. while inside my web.config file i only have one provider entity,, so from where did the entity on line 251 came from??? can u adivce ?

Comment: Well, if you did a full text search for "MySql" and didn't find anything in your solution, the next place I would look would be at the IIS config file.  Open up IIS Manager --> Management --> Configuration Editor and see if it's in there.  Also, just to rule it out, can you recycle the app pool and stop and restart the website?

Comment: inside the machine.config under this location "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config" , i removed the following reference

Comment: " <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" ...

Comment: minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />"and now the error did not show again. but not sure if removing this from the machoine.config file will cause any problems ?

Comment: If you don't want to remove it from your machine config, you can try explicitly removing it in your web.config.  Add a <remove> node to your providers and remove it by name.  See Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aykw9a6d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: but is this needed to be inside my machine.config ?

Comment: Depends if you have any other sites running on your machine that are using it.  Maybe at one time someone installed wordpress or something that uses MySql and it got added in there.  Hard to say if you need it without knowing what else is on your machine.  Since it's not MS SqlServer, the only thing I can say for sure is that it wasn't part of your default Windows install.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

What assemblies do you have referenced in your project? If you're not using the MySQL library, you can remove it. If you want to keep the reference, make sure you've got the correct version of the library added.

Comment: as i mentioned i do not have any mysql assemblies or references inside my viual studio project...

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config file.  There may be a reference to it floating around in there somewhere.